# Mellanox IS5031 switch field upgrade to 36-port switch

Tags: mellanox

We bought IS5031 switch and found only top 18 ports works. The [website](http://www.mellanox.com/page/products_dyn?product_family=73&menu_section=49) says

> This stand-alone switch is available as an 18-port switch that can be field upgraded to a 36-port switch

But no further instruction is shown for this upgrade. What shall we do for this upgrade? Thanks.

Comment: Get a license key from Mellanox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact your reseller and purchase the appropriate license key. See the part numbers at the bottom of the [datasheet](http://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_ib_switch_systems/pb_IS5031.pdf). They will need the serial number and then provide you with a license key.

Log into the switch CLI and enter the provided license key:

> switch (config) # license install PROVIDED-KEY

The other 18 ports should now work.

Comment: Thanks. But all retailers I contacted say the model is old and they don't have it. Anyway, thanks.